# How to select and calculate with value from specific variable in dataframe with pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, selection, calculation

I am running below code and get this:

```
import pandas as pd
pf=pd.read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/08kuxi50d0xqnfc/demo.csv?dl=1")
x=pf[pf['fuv1'] == 0].count()*100/1892
x
id          0.528541
date        0.528541
count       0.528541
idade       0.528541
site        0.528541
baseline    0.528541
fuv1        0.528541
fuv2        0.475687
fuv3        0.528541
fuv4        0.475687
dtype: float64
```

What I want is just to get this result **0.528541** and forgot all the above results.

What to do?
Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael, what do you know about this? I just want **fuv1 result** only!

Comment: I understand now, both solution works (`pf.loc[pf['fuv1'] == 0, 'fuv1'].count()*100/1892`) or `(pf['fuv1'] == 0).sum()*100/1892`. With `sum` should be faster in larger `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want count number of `0` values in column `fuv1` use `sum` for count `True`s which are processes like `1`s:

```
print ((pf['fuv1'] == 0).sum())
10

x = (pf['fuv1'] == 0).sum()*100/1892
print (x)
0.528541226216
```

Explanation why different outputs - [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) exclude `NaN`s:

```
pf=pd.read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/08kuxi50d0xqnfc/demo.csv?dl=1")
x=pf[pf['fuv1'] == 0]
print (x)
    id       date  count  idade site  baseline  fuv1  fuv2  fuv3  fuv4
0    0   4/1/2016     10     13    A         1   0.0   1.0   0.0   1.0
2    2   4/3/2016      9      5    C         1   0.0   NaN   0.0   1.0
3    3   4/4/2016    108     96    D         1   0.0   1.0   0.0   NaN
11  11  4/12/2016      6     13    C         1   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0
13  13  4/14/2016     12      4    C         1   0.0   1.0   1.0   0.0
40  40  5/11/2016     14      7    C         1   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
41  41  5/12/2016      0     26    C         1   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
42  42  5/13/2016     10     15    C         1   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
60  60  5/31/2016     13      3    D         1   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0
74  74  6/14/2016     15      7    B         1   0.0   1.0   1.0   1.0

print (x.count())
id          10
date        10
count       10
idade       10
site        10
baseline    10
fuv1        10
fuv2         9
fuv3        10
fuv4         9
dtype: int64
```

Comment: how to round for 2 decimal digits here: x = (pf['fuv1'] == 0).sum()*100/1892

Comment: Use `x = round((pf['fuv1'] == 0).sum()*100/1892, 2)`, because working with scalar

Comment: did you see the ouput of your proposed code? Does it gives o.53 as result?

Comment: Yes, it return`0.53`  Do you get something else?

Comment: i get 0.53000000000000003 as before asking you

Comment: Yes, I understand. There is problem float accuraccy, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/455612/2901002)

Comment: I found over ther this simplest solution 
    x = round((pf['fuv1'] == 0).sum()*100/1892, 2)
    format(x, '.2f') and returns '0.53' instead of 0.53
But i am not satisfied,
I need simplest solution like round within vector.

Comment: why does trick works? 
    print (round((pf['fuv1'] == 0).sum()*100/1892, 2))
I was trying myself.

Comment: I need to work with vector so this print (round((pf['fuv1'] == 0).sum()*100/1892, 2)) for me will not help. I want to include the vector in that function you fixed before.

Comment: @MGB.py - do you want [`round`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.round.html) ?

Comment: @MGB.py - If want use `format` - `df['col'].apply(lambda x: format(x, '.2f'))`

Comment: I did not understand.

Comment: You like `format` solution, so if need apply it to column use solution above. ;)

Comment: like this?? pf['fuv1'].apply(lambda x: format(x, '.2f'))
Doesnot work...

Comment: It does not work, because there are not floats. test it by new column like `pf['test'] = pf['count'].div(3456)` and then `pf['new'] = pf['test'].apply(lambda x: format(x, '.2f'))`

Comment: pf.dtypes
id            int64
date         object
count         int64
idade         int64
site         object
baseline      int64
fuv1        float64
fuv2        float64
fuv3        float64
fuv4        float64
dtype: object

Comment: Not understand.

Comment: they are float. Maybe I need to convert to int before applying the simplest round. How to convert?

Comment: hmmm, but there are in `fuv1` only floats with `0`, so why do you need round? Or values are changed?

Comment: because I need to calculate the percentage of fuv1=0 in 1892

Comment: but why it is array? Not scalar?

Comment: I am confuse with the terminology: array and scalar. Can you test them as the dataset is accessible?

Comment: scalar is one number, 1d array in pandas is Series (column of dataframe). 2d array is DataFrame.

Comment: if you can transform this print (round((pf['fuv1'] == 0).sum()*100/1892, 2)) into vector I could be very satisfied.

Comment: I am a bit confused, what is vector? what is expected output? New column?

Comment: I call the below as a vector:

x = print (round((pf['fuv1'] == 0).sum()*100/1892, 2))

Comment: here X is vector for me ;-)

Comment: X is ignored and it return the result 0.53 instead of not printing result and wait for request for the value of X

Comment: I dont understand. `x = 0.53` it assign `0.53` to variable `x`. But it is not vector. What python or pandas structure need? There is no data structure vector. :(

Comment: I am posting below an answer what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you need `x = round((pf['fuv1'] == 0).sum()*100/1892, 2)`, right?

Comment: `x = round((pf['fuv1'] == 0).sum()*100/1892, 2)` does not work?

Answer (score 2):

```
In [282]: pf.loc[pf['fuv1'] == 0, 'id'].count()*100/1892
Out[282]: 0.5285412262156448
```

Comment: do you know simplest  to round the output?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

pf=pd.read_csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/08kuxi50d0xqnfc/demo.csv?dl=1")

x = (pf['fuv1'] == 0).sum()*100/1892
y=pf["idade"].mean()

l = "Performance"
k = "LTFU"


def test(l1,k1):
    return pd.DataFrame({'a':[l1, k1], 'b':[x, y]})

df1 = test(l,k)
df1.columns = [''] * len(df1.columns)   
df1.index = [''] * len(df1.index)   

print(round(df1, 2))

  Performance   0.53
         LTFU  14.13
```

Comment: @jezrael, I want to remove arrays o and 1 here to be fully satisfied.

Comment: need `df1.index= [''] * len(df1.index)`

Comment: @jezrael, you are almost there: you removed '0' and '1' but you brought back columns names 'a' and 'b'. :-(

Comment: I think `df1.columns = [''] * len(df1.columns)` and `df1.index= [''] * len(df1.index)`

Comment: @jezrael, SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

Comment: But it is really awfull hack. :(

Comment: @jezrael, please post the code as an answer to let me copy and paste.Thanks

Comment: @jezrael, the problem was that I was adding 'and' in the synthax. :-(